# ProductCode (GUID) for Autoloading DLL for AutoCAD

Tags: guid, autoload, autocad

I would like to know where the ProductCode (GUID) of an autoloading DLL for AutoCAD is coming from. I have developed a plugin in DLL that has some commands for AutoCAD. I follow a "known good" example program and create a bundle for my plugin. The DLL failed to autoload  for some reason. I am wondering may be the ProductCode (GUID) that I have entered in PackageContents.xml is wrong. That's why I want to find out the correct way to find a ProductCode.

Based on the example program, I am sure that the ProductCode is NOT the GUID stated in  section in the Visual Studio project file.  And I am also sure that the ProductCode is NOT the GUID stored in AssemblyInfo.cs file either.

Should I use the GUID inside the DLL file? But I have no way to tell which GUID is embedded inside the DLL file.

As of now, I simply use the GUID generated using Visual Studio --> Tools --> Create GUID. But I don't know if this is the right GUID to use. Or does this really matter which GUID to use as long as it is unique?

Please help. Thanks.

Jay Chan

Comment: If this is a .NET dll, personally I have been using the registry for autoloading, and found it really easy to set up with no issues. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46897472/7159784). There are some links you can follow in the post that explain how to set up the registry. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your link to a web page that shows many different ways to autoload.  That is a "keeper".  Anyway, this is a different topic.  For my question here, I am interested to know where you get your GUID.  I suppose when you use your way to register your plugin for AutoCAD, you will need to enter a GUID into the registry, right?  Where do you get that GUID?  Do you get it through Visual Studio --> Tools --> Create GUID?  Please let me know.

Comment: No, you do not need the GUID for that, just a path to your dll. It is quite easy, here's a [direct link](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-autoload-DLLs-with-AutoCAD.html). Scroll down to "Solution B". I am not saying this is the best solution, I am saying that it has worked well for me!

Comment: Thanks for explaining that I don't need a GUID when I register the DLL.  Just an off-topic question: I assume you use a script to add your settings into the registry, and I assume you use regasm.exe to run the script.  Which version of regasm.exe that you use to register your DLL/EXE?  regasm.exe is not in the search PATH.  There are multiple copies of regasm.exe in various folders under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new PackageContents.xml file for your bundle, you have to create a new GUID (menu Tools > Create a Guid) as ProductCode and an another one as UpgradeCode, then, for each new version of your application, you should create a new GUID for the ProductCode but never change the UpgradeCode one.
If you also build an installer (Windows Installer), a good practice is to set the same GUIDs for ProductCode and UpgradeCode in the PackageContents as those generated by VisualStudio for the installer.
More details about Autoloader here:
http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/01/autodesk-autoloader-white-paper.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, I understand that I need a GUID in PackageContents.xml, and I am glad to hear that you have confirmed that the GUID is the one that I get from Tools --> Create Guid.  This is what I need to know.